# Does Azure AppService platform support Azure AD v2.0 endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Is it possible to use Azure AD v2.0 endpoint to authenticate in the Azure AppService platform? Just want to make sure it's possible before doing any investments in MSAL.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I known, we cannot use v2 endpoint to authenticate Azure Web App in Azure Portal for now.

Currently, authentication providers in Azure Web App service contain Azure Active Directory and it use v1 ednpoint to redirect.

You can post this idea in [this Uservoice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) and Azure Team will review it .

Hope this helps!

---

**Update:**

Actually, you can use v2 endpoint app to authenticate Azure Web App.But you can only use Microsoft Account to access the Applicaiton.

You can follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication) to configure your App Service application to use Microsoft Account login. I test it and I created the Converged application in my application registration portal. Finally I can only use my live account to login.

**NOTE: with this configuration, you can not use AAD Account to login.**

Answer (score 0):

As Wayne Yang said, this is not supported by App Service via the "easy auth" yet. But you can integrate with Azure AD v2 endpoint with just about any standard OpenID Connect library.

ASP.NET Core has [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/) for instance.

Comment: Sure. I was just planning to use Azure Functions with the built in Authentication in the portal